# Jasper plugin for Grails: Cannot invoke method generateReport() on null object

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper plugin (v 1.5.3) for Grails (v 1.3.7). I have written following code in a method of a Service

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperExportFormat;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperReportDef;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

class ReportService {

    static transactional = true
    def jasperService

    def generateFormA() {
        def reportDef = new JasperReportDef(name:'test.jasper', fileFormat:JasperExportFormat.PDF_FORMAT)   
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File('C:/test.pdf'), jasperService.generateReport(reportDef).toByteArray())

        return
    }
}
```

I am getting following run-time error when I call the Service method -

> Cannot invoke method generateReport() on null object

I have injected jasperService and imported required classes as described in the [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jasper) page. Moreover, when I debug, I noticed that reportDef is being instantiated properly.

Can anyone suggest anything. Appreciate your help.

Comment: what do you mean *you* 'injected' the jasperService? - grails does this for you.  Can you show where it's defined?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have edited my original post to include the complete Service. I call `generateFormA()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael, thanks for the insight.

To get a better idea about the scenes behind curtain, I downloaded the plugin source code and used directly in my application. Turns out, **JasperService** class of the plugin uses **dataSource** bean.

```
class JasperService {
    boolean transactional = true
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSource
    .....
    private JasperPrint generatePrinter(JasperReportDef reportDef) {
        .....
        def conn = dataSource.getConnection()
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(resource.inputStream, reportDef.parameters, conn)
        .....
    }
    ...........
}
```

But, dataSource is not being instantiated when dataSource.getConnection() method is called (which, in turn, *throwing the null object error*). May be this has something to do with Grails itself, not the plugin. So I modified the JasperPrint() method of JasperService class like below and it worked

```
def dataSource = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.dataSource
def conn = dataSource.getConnection()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks fine and this should work.  I would try stopping the app and running the grails [clean](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/clean.html) command.  Sometimes this helps.